# How do I calculate a value in a model based on children of that model in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, data-modeling

I'm new to rails and I can think of several ways to solve this problem, but I'd like to do it the "rails" way. My problem is that I have a model - exam - which :has_many questions. I'd like to write a function in the exam model which will calculate the score for the exam (and store it in the exam model). To do this, I need to read data from the question objects that belong to the exam.

Any tips or links to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not enough of information. What is a score? How do you want to count it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you didn't write anything about your data structure let's imagine that your every question has_got Boolean `correct` field. And your exam has got Integer `total_score` field. So after examing it should count all questions with correct answer:

```
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  before_save :set_score

  def set_score
    total_score = questions.where(:correct => true).count
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks fl00r. This is exactly what I was looking for. The data model that you guessed is pretty much what I'm doing. I like the idea of saving the score using the before_save method.  Thanks again.